# Some triangle symbols are not showing, diamond and squares not showing at all on D3 V5

Tags: d3.js, symbols, linechart

[image]I'm a D3 newbie, trying to show symbols on a muli-line line chart with D3
. a line of them should have circles in the data points positions and they show well, the other 3 lines, one should have triangles, one should have diamonds, and the last one should have squares. The triangles are showing 10 out the the 16 points, the diamonds and squares don't show at all. There is no errors in the console. Any help??

```
var symbolGenerator = d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolTriangle);

    svg2.selectAll('path')
    .data(six)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr('d', function(d,i) {
        symbolGenerator
            .size(deaths[i]/1000+100);
         return symbolGenerator();
    })
    .attr("fill", color_scheme['6_6.9'])
    .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
        return 'translate(' + xScale(year[i]) + ',' + yScale(six[i])+') ';
    });

    console.log(six);
   console.log(seven);

    var symbolGenerator1 = d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolDiamond);
    svg2.selectAll('path')
    .data(seven)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr('d', function(d,i) {
        symbolGenerator1.size(100);
         return symbolGenerator1();
    })
    .attr("fill", color_scheme['7_7.9'])
    .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
        return 'translate(' + xScale(year[i]) + ',' + yScale(seven[i])+') ';
    });

    var arc = d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolSquare);
    //alert(arc);
    svg2.selectAll('path')
    .data(eight)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", function(d,i) {
        arc.size(500);
         return arc();
    })
    .attr("fill", color_scheme['8.0+'])
    .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
        return 'translate(' + xScale(year[i]) + ',' + yScale(eight[i])+') ';
    });*emphasized text*
```

Comment: have you checked the dom tree to confirm the "missing" symbols are not rendering outside the boundary of the svg?

Comment: Could you please create a working instance of your issue ?